# How do I use pbcopy in a bash function? Can it be scripted?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, pbcopy

I often find myself copying history commands to my clipboard using this:

`echo !123 | pbcopy`

This works fine from the Terminal. Assuming `!123 = cd ..`, it looks something like this:

```
$ echo !123 | pbcopy
echo cd .. | pbcopy
    //result: `cd ..` is in the clipboard
```

To make life easier, I added this bash function to my .bashrc:

```
function pb() {
    echo $1 | pbcopy
}
```

This command would be invoked, ideally, like this: `pb !!`. However, this doesn't work. Here is what happens:

```
$ pb !123
pb cd .. | pbcopy
    //result: `!!` is in the clipboard
```

No matter what history command I invoke, it always returns `!!` to the clipboard. I tried making an alias too, but that shares the same problem:

`alias pb='echo !! | pbcopy'`

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you aware that you do a reverse search on the history using `Ctrl-R`.

Comment: yes I am. However that doesn't copy anything to clipboard (for use in other programs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your function is somewhat wrong. It should use `$@` instead of `$1`

that is

```
function pb() {
    echo "$@" | pbcopy
}
```

The result:

```
samveen@minime:/tmp $ function pb () { echo "$@" | pbcopy ; }
samveen@minime:/tmp $ pb !2030
pb file `which bzcat`
    //result: `file /bin/bzcat` is in the clipboard
samveen@minime:/tmp $
```

To explain why the `alias` doesn't work, the `!!` is inside single quotes, and history replacement happens if `!!` isn't quoted. As it is a replacement on the command history, which is interactive by definition, saving it into variables and aliases is very tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `fc -l -1` or `history -p '!!'` to print the last history entry:

```
pb() {
  [[ $# = 0 ]] && local n=-1 || local n="$1 $1"
  fc -l $n | cut -d' ' -f2- | printf %s "$(cat)" | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbcopy
}
```

If LC_CTYPE is C, pbcopy garbles up non-ASCII characters. Terminal and iTerm set the locale variables to something like en_US.UTF-8 by default though.